# MSBuild "GenerateFakes" Error MSB4127, MSB4060

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

When building using Visual Studio 2013 the GenerateFakes succeeds, it uses the same path to the same target file.

When building via MSBuild 12.0 (Same version shipped with Visual Studio 2013) I get the following two errors.

**Error #1**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets(128,5): error MSB4127: The "GenerateFakes" task could not be instantiated from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Tasks.dll". Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your computer and that your host application is not missing a binding redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.GenerateFakes' to type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.
```

**Error #2**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets(128,5): error MSB4060: The "GenerateFakes" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
```

I could successfully build using MSBuild 11.0 on an old machine which was using Visual Studio 2012.

**Could the issue be related to some sort of missing binding redirect?**

The following link contains a similar error but for another framework: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2772a075-4e2f-42af-9e7a-2228b794368e/msbuild-crashes-with-a-message-task-could-not-be-instantiated-exception

**Just noticed that deleting the FakeAssemblies folder in all projects cures the problem, however once I build in Visual Studio again the error comes back.**

Comment: If you are using MSTest, Fakes will not succeed. If you are using the Visual Studio Test Runner, Fakes will succeed. Visual Studio must be installed on the build server. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Magnus i'm not sure, this is when compiling the code on my development machine not on the build server. (I use MSBuild because we have several solutions, and it allows me to only have one instance of Visual Studio open).

Comment: Well, Janck, it's usually more an issue with testing than building. If it did indeed work in 2012, it may be a real bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the issue i've had to set the VisualStudioVersion to 12.0 in the global properties. This needs to be done both when running MSBuild.exe from the command line, or when using the MSBuild API.

**Using the API:**

I have had to manually reference the MSBuild 12.0 Dlls which can be found in `Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin`

Next copied the assembly redirects from `MSBuild.exe.config` and pasted them into my app.config.

```
  <runtime>
    <DisableFXClosureWalk enabled="true" />
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Engine" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: This runtime section copied to my .config saved me! Was trying to build a project using MSBuild's API withing a C# code. I was failing with the following error: The "CheckPathAttributes" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

See the script of your Visual Studio project (.csproj) file. You can  open it in Notepad. The What is the ToolsVersion of the file? If it is 4.0, you need to use MSbuild 4.0 to build it.

Visual Studio 2013 continues to use MSBuild 4.0 for projects that has a toolVersion set to 4.0.

Comment: Hamid the ToolsVersion is 4.0 in the project file, but the MSBuild executable ran by VS 2013 is 12.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe) this build seems to be successful.

Comment: Can you please share your build logs please. Also are you using using the full path of msbuild.exe 12.0 when running msbuild i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSbuild\12.0\bin"

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue could be something related to the issue seen in this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2772a075-4e2f-42af-9e7a-2228b794368e/msbuild-crashes-with-a-message-task-could-not-be-instantiated-exception